# One of the styles I created in styles.xml is not applied to TextView in Java but the other 2 styles I made work fine

Tags: java

I'm new to Stackoverflow but not that new to coding. 
I have this simple flyer I made in Android Studio.
I'm trying to apply different styles to different TextViews. 
The first two styles shown work on all TextViews but the third style named "address_style" won't apply for some reason. 
The TextView goes away completely when I apply it as a style. 
I've tried a couple of different things. 
I just don't get why the third style won't work. 
Can someone help me out?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

```
<style name="Title">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:text">@string/Title</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#2196F3</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>

<style name="textView">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:background">#CCBBDEFB</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#F44336</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
</style>

<style name="address_style">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">14dp</item>
    <item name="android:text">@string/address</item>
    <item name="android:background">#CCBBDEFB</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding ="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/soccer" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    style="@style/Title"
    android:fontFamily="@font/hanalei_fill"
    android:text="@string/Title" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:fontFamily="@font/trade_winds"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/textUnderTitle"
    android:textColor="#03A9F4"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    style="@style/textView"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView2"
    android:fontFamily="@font/carter_one"
    android:text="@string/price" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    style="@style/textView"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView3"
    android:fontFamily="@font/carter_one"
    android:text="@string/seasons" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    style="@style/textView"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView4"
    android:fontFamily="@font/carter_one"
    android:text="@string/whatYouLearn" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    style="@style/textView"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView5"
    android:fontFamily="@font/carter_one"
    android:text="@string/allAges" />

<TextView
    style="@style/textView"
    android:layout_above="@id/register"
    android:fontFamily="@font/trade_winds"
    android:text="@string/address" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/register"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:autoLink="all"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:fontFamily="@font/carter_one"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/web_address"
    android:textColor="#2196F3"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I feel stupid. I finally saw the little red exclamation point in the red stop sign in my preview of the activity_main box. It told me one of the styles is not registering(address_style) and gave me an option to refresh the styles.xml page. And now it works. I didn't know that could cause an error because there were no problems with the other two styles I created.